# Oauth2 authorised routes not working in Ktor

Tags: oauth-2.0, ktor

My aim is to get a GitHub Oauth token to allow access to GitHub data and to provide access control to other Ktor routes in a web app.
I simplified the Ktor sample to only use GitHub and that works fine & gets a token from GitHub.
However, the other routes in the authenticate block are never called. For example, /github/repos is recognised as a route (no 404) but re-authenticates with GitHub and displays the 'successful login' page rather than "Get and display repos info from GitHib". I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental but any help gratefully received.
Thanks, Martin

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.auth.*
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.apache.*
import io.ktor.html.*
import io.ktor.locations.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import kotlinx.html.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


val githubProvider = OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
    name = "github",
    authorizeUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize",
    accessTokenUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
    clientId = "**client-id**",
    clientSecret = "**client-secret**",
    defaultScopes = listOf("repo", "user")
)

@Location("/home") class home
@Location("/github/login") class gitHubLogin
@Location("/github/repos") class gitHubRepos
@Location("/github/user") class gitHubUser

@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port=8081) {
        module()
    }.start()
}

@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
fun Application.mainModule() {
    install(Authentication) {
        oauth("gitHubOAuth") {
            client = HttpClient(Apache)
            providerLookup = { githubProvider }
            urlProvider = { url(gitHubLogin()) }
        }
    }
    install(Locations)
    install(Routing)

    routing {
        get<home> {
            call.respondHtml {
                head {
                    title { +"index page" }
                }
                body {
                    h1 {
                        +"Try to login"
                    }
                    p {
                        a(href = locations.href(gitHubLogin())) {
                            +"Login"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        authenticate("gitHubOAuth") {
            location<gitHubLogin>() {
                param("error") {
                    handle {
                        call.loginFailedPage(call.parameters.getAll("error").orEmpty())
                    }
                }
                handle {
                    val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2>()
                    if (principal != null) {
                        call.loggedInSuccessResponse(principal)
                    } else {
                        call.loginPage()
                    }
                }
            }
            get<gitHubUser> {
                call.respondHtml {
                    body {
                        p { +"Get and display user info from GitHib" }
                    }
                }
            }
            get<gitHubRepos> {
                call.respondHtml {
                    body {
                        p { +"Get and display repos info from GitHib" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
private suspend fun ApplicationCall.loginPage() {
    respondHtml {
        head {
            title { +"Login with" }
        }
        body {
            h1 {
                +"Login with:"
            }

            p {
                a(href = application.locations.href(gitHubLogin())) {
                    +"GitHub"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun ApplicationCall.loginFailedPage(errors: List<String>) {
    respondHtml {
        head {
            title { +"Login with" }
        }
        body {
            h1 {
                +"Login error"
            }

            for (e in errors) {
                p {
                    +e
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
private suspend fun ApplicationCall.loggedInSuccessResponse(callback: OAuthAccessTokenResponse?) {
    respondHtml {
        head {
            title { +"Logged in" }
        }
        body {
            h1 {
                +"You are logged in"
            }
            p {
                +"Your token is $callback"
            }
            ul {
                li {
                    a(href = locations.href(gitHubUser())) { +"User" }
                }
                li {
                    a(href = locations.href(gitHubRepos())) { +"Repos" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OAuth process is repeated for each client's request to any of the protected (under `authenticate` block) routes. You can use unrestricted routes to provide access to resources which require token. In the handlers for those routes, you can check if a client successfully passes authentication or not. If yes then you can get a token from the session or from tokens' storage associated with the session and use it to acquire data from a resource server; if no then redirect a client to a login endpoint or show an error message. To make it work you can use [Sessions](https://ktor.io/docs/sessions.html) to retain knowledge about successful authentications.

Here follows an example of storing tokens directly in sessions.

Configure `Sessions`:

```
data class LoginSession(val token: String)

// ...
install(Sessions) {
    cookie<LoginSession>("LOGIN_SESSION")
}
```

Save session in the handler for callback URL route:

```
get("callback") {
    val principal = call.authentication.principal<OAuthAccessTokenResponse.OAuth2>()

    if (principal != null) {
        call.sessions.set(LoginSession(token = principal.accessToken))
    }
}
```

Use non-restricted route to provide an access to some resource:

```
get("repos") {
    val repos = call.withAuth { session ->
        HttpClient(Apache).get<String>("https://api.github.com/user/repos") {
            header("Authorization", "token ${session.token}")
        }
    }

    call.respondText { repos }
}
```

The `ApplicationCall.withAuth` method is just a helper for checking existence of a session:

```
suspend fun <T: Any> ApplicationCall.withAuth(block: suspend (session: LoginSession) -> T): T {
    val session = sessions.get<LoginSession>()

    if (session != null) {
        return block(session)
    }

    respondRedirect("/login")
    throw Exception("Not authenticated")
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer that makes complete sense.